# How to disable the default copy behavior in QTreeView?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtreeview

I have a `QTreeView` with a `QStandardItemModel` and I would like to be able to prevent the user from copying the text of the items.

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QTreeView>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr) :
        QMainWindow(parent)
    {
        auto *treeView = new QTreeView(this);
        auto *model = new QStandardItemModel(this);

        for (int n = 0; n < 5; n++)
            model->appendRow(createItem(QString::number(n)));

        treeView->setModel(model);
        treeView->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::NoContextMenu);

        setCentralWidget(treeView);
    }

private:
    QStandardItem *createItem(const QString &name)
    {
        auto *item = new QStandardItem(name);

        item->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsEnabled);

        return item;
    }
};
```

I have already made the items not editable and disabled the context menu. However, it is still possible for the user to click on an item and copy the text by pressing `Ctrl+C`. I can use `Qt::NoItemFlags`, but I want the items to be enabled.

How to accomplish that?

Comment: **Note:** This question and its answer are posted as suggested in [this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374267/what-is-the-correct-action-when-a-question-has-been-deleted-right-after-the-op-h/374271#374271) in order to help anyone who would like to know how to achieve this.

Comment: @Adinia, I do not mind the edit. However, this info is important, so l will put it as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable the default copy behavior of `QTreeView` reimplement `QTreeView::keyPressEvent` in a subclass, e.g. `TreeView`, like that:

```
void TreeView::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    if (!(event == QKeySequence::Copy))
        QTreeView::keyPressEvent(event);
}
```

Then in your code instead of `QTreeView`:

```
auto *treeView = new QTreeView(this);
```

instantiate `TreeView`:

```
auto *treeView = new TreeView(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use installEventFilter to trap the keystroke events with having to subclass.